# What to do if OP's effort demonstration may possibly answered the question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I found this question about html and css:

[How to make the button on the CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277007)

Besides the requests shown in an image, OP also puts some html and css into the question. While OP doesn't specify it is an answer, I found the results looks similar to the request shown in the image.I'm troubling to determine if the shown code is noise because:

1. If it is interpret as noise, then edit out the 'effort' and result as a 'do my work' question
2. If it is interpreted as additional information rather than noise, it may indicate the question is unclear, ie: missing additional requirements

Which interpret is more correct? And if we want to improve the question, should we delete the 'effort' or just closed as unclear, or other options?

Comment: I would vote for unclear, no description of what's failing or whatever.. It seems it is what OP is using and probably not working as expected, so I wouldn't remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to make this button in css that is not stupid to expose background-image and impose it

Yeah, sorry, that sentence doesn't make any sense. I suspect this is [Babelfishian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_Fish_(website)) or some other form of meaning-lost-in-translation. Since it's the only thing we have to hang our hat on here, I've closed the question as *unclear what you're asking.*

Answer (score 2):

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41277007/1) was very poor:

> How to make this button in css that is not stupid to expose
>   background-image and impose it
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9TMo.jpg

OP only edited his post after he was requested to in comments. Look at the edit revision [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41277007/2):

[image]

I'm not HTML and CSS expert, but if the info is enough to make the post clear and useful, the downvotes should be removed.